# Jmeter Load testing

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I am hitting 150 users per second in jmeter for hls video and it is giving me a response time of around 8 minutes. What if I hit a real time user from another PC. Will that user also take 8 minutes. How can I check that the report given by jmeter is real?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [The New HLS Plugin for JMeter - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-hls-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide)

> In a HTTP Live Streaming process:
>
> 1. The audio/video to be streamed is reproduced by a media encoder at different quality levels, bitrates and resolutions. Each version is called a variant.
> 2. The different variants are split up into smaller Media Segment Files.
> 3. The encoder creates a Media Playlist for each variant with the URLs of each Media Segment.
> 4. The encoder creates a Master Playlist File with the URLs of each Media Playlist.
>
> **To play, the client first downloads the Master Playlist, and then the Media Playlists. Then, they play each Media Segment declared within the chosen Media Playlist.** The client can reload the Playlist to discover any added segments. This is needed in cases of live events, for example.

So given well-behaved JMeter HLS test response time will be equal to your video duration.

Testing video streams is not the same as testing web applications and you should be looking for different metrics paying more attention on monitoring server-side events using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).

Comment: @ Dimitri .............Thank you for the clarification! Really helpful !

Comment: Means the response time 8 min is for the complete video streaming. Not the time taken to play the video.  I am using hls plugin to test it